# what files does pip depend on when listing/showing available packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

On my windows machine, and in a virtualenv(I named `vcfs`), whenever I enter the command  `pip list` or `pip show package-name`, it shows me the packages from another virtualenv (I named `test`). I assume pip must be reading a file from somewhere in order to display those wrong listing.

The problem is partly my fault because I copied the files in the `\script` and `\site-packages` folder of the "wrong" virtualenv (named `test`) to the env of the pip showing the wrong list (named `vcfs`) because I didn't have internet connection when I was trying to setup the new virtualenv (`vcfs`).

I'm using `virtualenvwrapper-win-1.2.1`, and `virtualenv-13.1.2` which bundles `pip version 7.1.2` on `python2.7`.

**sample:**
the directory for the new virtualenv is

`C:\Users\Timothy Ebiuwhe\Documents\test scipts\python\vcfs`,

while the directory for the old/wrong virtualenv is

`C:\Users\Timothy Ebiuwhe\Documents\test scipts\python\test`

but when I enter `pip show mock` (with the `vcfs` activated), I get

> (vcfs) C:\Users\Timothy Ebiuwhe\Downloads>pip show mock
>   Metadata-Version: 2.0
>   Name: mock
>   Version: 1.3.0
>   Summary: Rolling backport of unittest.mock for all Pythons
>   Home-page: https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock
>   Author: Testing Cabal
>   Author-email: testing-in-python@lists.idyll.org
>   License: UNKNOWN
>   Location: c:\users\user\documents\test
>   scipts\python\**test**\lib\site-packages
>   Requires: funcsigs, pbr, six

Which is the mock package from the wrong virtualenv (`test`)!

I could create the virtualenv again from scratch but I've gone through alot already in trying to install most of the packages including `scrapy` which is really painful to install especially from my very slow internet connection.

I've already done some research on the problem but most other people's problem were on a *nix machine and a simple !#shebang fix solved theirs. But pip on windows uses a .exe file(no shebang). So I'm assuming pip is reading a file somewhere that points back to the old/wrong virtualenv. I've checked out easy-install.pth, virtual_path_extensions.pth, and a few other files(and even got to fix some of them but pip still does the wrong thing).

Comment: `pip` will self detect its environment and select `site-packages` accordingly.

Comment: sure. But I need to know how the "environment detection" algorithm works so I could narrow down the search for the solution of my problem.

Comment: Basically, it does:  `from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_lib())`

Comment: tried that but it prints out what it was meant to print "C:\Users\Timothy Ebiuwhe\Documents\test scipts\python\vcfs\Lib\site-packages" ...